# How to find Mac Apps using the iTunes API?

Tags: ios, macos, itunes

I'm trying to find a solution to search for Mac Apps using the iTunes API.
My JSON and PHP Scripts are both working on finding iPhone or iPad Apps, but I'm not able to find Mac Apps the last few days.

I normally used this URL to find the iPhone/iPad(universal) App Pages, as well as the Mac App.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=software,iPadSoftware,macSoftware&country=de&limit=50&term=Pages
```

But somehow I can't find the Mac App. If I'm searching only for the Mac App using the following URL, there aren't any results.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=macSoftware&country=de&limit=50&term=Pages
```

Looking at the API description here http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html it should work.

If I search the App directly by its ID, it works also

```
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?country=de&id=409201541
```

And looking at the kind, there you can find "mac-software", but searching for "mac-software" doesn't work as well.

So, please help me finding a URL (like the first one, but working), where Mac Apps displayed as well as iPad or iPhone Apps.

Comment: Curious; according to the page, that should definitely be working.  I highly recommend filing a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Ok, thanks! I just submitted the bug report ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kinda broken at the moment.  If you force an attribute it'll start finding apps.

`https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=macSoftware&country=de&limit=50&term=Pages&attribute=allTrackTerm`

Also, if you set media to software along with that. allTrackTerm is no longer available and the only thing you useful you can use is keywordsTerm. Though that has it's own issues

Comment: Oh, great thanks! It seems like this works fine ;) Just needed this to finish my project on appkit.appleme.de (localization missing atm.).

Comment: But there is one little problem. Is there a possibility to sort the apps by publicity or something like that right in the URL? Because if I'm searching for software,iPadSoftware,macSoftware the results are first iPhone, then iPad and last mac, but not mixed, so if there are 200 iPhone apps matching pages, the pages mac app won't be displayed at all...